# How to get kNN in python (visual studio)? I thought it was part of sklearn?

Tags: python, visual-studio, knn

I tried to import it

```
from numpy import *
import kNN
from matplotlib import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from os import *
```

but kNN is highlighted with an error: ImportError: No module named kNN

Comment: ... why do you expect there to be a module called `kNN`?

Comment: from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

Answer (score 1):

`from sklearn import neighbors`

[Scikit Learn documentation example for KNN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html). Documentation is useful! Please try looking there next time before asking questions on StackOverflow.